# Dados retornando com espaço

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Estou fazendo uma chamada `ajax` com o jQuery em um controller no `CodeIgniter`. O problema é que quando o `jQuery` me retorna os dados, ele está vindo com alguns espaços na frente do resultado, ficando por exemplo:
`(ESPAÇO) (ESPAÇO) (ESPAÇO) sucesso`. O problema não sei onde pode ser, pois o model e controller estão corretos:

**Model**

```
public function AdicionarAoCarrinho($codigo){

            $this->db->where('estoque > ', $this->limiteEstoque);
            $this->db->where('codigo', $codigo);

            $produto = $this->db->get('produtos');

            if($produto->num_rows() > 0){


            if(!$this->session->userdata('session_user')){

               $sessao =  $this->session->set_userdata('session_user', md5(time()+rand(32401, 460312)));

            }else{

                $sessao = $this->session->userdata('session_user');
            }

            $dataProdutoCarrinho = array(
                                                                'id_session'=>$sessao,
                                                                'id_produto'=>$codigo
                                                                );

                if($this->db->insert('carrinho', $dataProdutoCarrinho)){

                    return 'sucesso';

                }else{

                    return 'erro';
                }

            }else{

                return 'estoque';
            }
        }
```

**Controller**

```
public function adicionar_carrinho(){

        if($this->input->post('codigo')){

            $codigo = $this->input->post('codigo');

            echo $this->produto_model->AdicionarAoCarrinho($codigo);
        }
    }
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("a.botao_comprar").click(function(){

            var codigo = $(this).attr('codigo');
            var baseURL = $("#baseURL").val();

            $.ajax({

                url: baseURL+'produto/adicionar_carrinho',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {codigo: codigo},

                success:function(callback){

                    alert(callback); //Coloquei o alert para ver, e nele sai os espaços e mesmo que saia "sucesso" ele me retorna o erro do ultimo else

                    if(callback == 'estoque'){

                        swal("Desculpe...", "Mas o produto que você está tentando comprar, não temos no estoque ;(", "error");

                    }else if(callback == 'sucesso'){

                        swal("Parabéns", "o produto foi adicionado com sucesso ao carrinho", "success");

                    }else{

                        swal("Oops...", "Ocorreu um erro desconhecido ao adicionar o produto no carrinho. Tente novamente, se o problema continuar, entre em contato conosco.", "error");

                    }
                }
            });
        })
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: Como solução paliativa tenta usar $.trim(callback)

Comment: o $.trim() deu certo, só que eu queria saber o porque desse problema

Comment: Por isso que eu não coloquei como resposta. Nunca usei esse framework.

Comment: Um achismo, será que vc deve colocar o **dataType** na requisição?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique adicionalmente a presença de espaços antes e após as tags de abertura e fechamento de código PHP ( `<?php .. ?>` ) nos arquivos do seu projeto. O recomendado inclusive é que a tag de fechamento (`?>`) não seja utilizada ao final dos arquivos.